# how to make thread in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

i need a simple program using `sleep()` and (`_begin thread()`) to make a thread on this program

```
void tdrow(){
    Sleep(50);
    move_bare_without_ball(a,b,windowsize);
    _beginthread(tdrow(),0,0);
}
```

Comment: down vote for homework smell

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need, look up the docs of `std::thread` or `boost::thread`

Comment: i want to make a thread from process.h to use _begin thread() and sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_beginthread` is a Visual C++ CRT function. I don't recommend using it or `process.h` for this purpose. Please use std::thread (or if your compiler is older, `boost::thread`).

If you were using `_beginthread`, you'd give it tdrow, not tdrow().

Comment: Okay. `_beginthread` was included for compatibility with VC++. Please enable Code::Blocks C++11 support and use std::thread.